# UIAlertController is Too Small

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

When I use `UIAlertController` on iOS9.0, I find it is too small.

```
UIAlertController * alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"title" message:@"XXXXXXXX" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction * cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {}];

UIAlertAction * sureAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"sure" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {}];
[alertVC addAction:cancelAction];
[alertVC addAction:sureAction];
[self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use runtime to change the method of `fontWithDescriptor:size:`,it can cause the problem.

```
+ (void)load {
   Method newMethod = class_getClassMethod([self class],   @selector(adjustFontWithDescriptor:size:));
   Method method = class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(fontWithDescriptor:size:));
method_exchangeImplementations(newMethod, method);
}
+ (UIFont *)adjustFontWithDescriptor:(UIFontDescriptor *)descriptor size:(CGFloat)fontSize{
   UIFont *newFont = nil;
   newFont = [UIFont adjustFontWithDescriptor:descriptor size:[UIFont adjustFontSize:fontSize]];
   return newFont;
}
+ (CGFloat)adjustFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize{
   //return fontSize * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 375;
   if (WIN_WIDTH==320) {
       return fontSize-2;
   }else if (WIN_WIDTH==375){
       return fontSize;
   }else{
      return fontSize+2;
   }
 }
```